# How to display the lock icon in the address bar, during a Basic HTTP Auth dialog?

Tags: google-chrome, basic-authentication

Google Chrome, Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) displays ⓘ instead of .

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to an `https://` page, protected by Basic HTTP Auth.
2. The *Sign in* dialog appears...
3. Look at the address bar, you'll see ⓘ instead of . ☚ **This is the problem.**
4. You can click the address bar twice to see: it's still `https://`.
5. **Cancel the dialog**, it becomes .
6. Reload the page, this time it's  during the dialog too...
7. ...until you visit an other site then come back, or try on a new tab.

> Test site: https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/

> You don't have to sign in, but if you want to, the user and password are both `guest`.

> To sign out without `chrome://restart`, use this code in the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>):

```js
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
        if (req.readyState == 4) location.reload();     
    };
    req.open('GET', location.href.replace('://', '://@'), true);
    req.send();
```